# Of the two variables (Q and V) in the equation of capacitor energy, which is better to take the average of?

Tags: potential-energy, graph-theory

$U_c = \frac{1}{2}QV$

I understand from the graph which it should be one half but not quarter, or taking the average of both.

But it doesn't really matter to me which variable is on y or x axis? (Though conventionally, people put C as x axis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is a very advanced question from someone in a college course who knows integral calculus or a high-school student who knows none of it, so let me answer it both ways. The high-school answer should be intelligible to the college student, so let's tackle that first.

Basically: You're not taking the average of either.

The expression is that you get an energy by a sum of little additions of little charges, $E = \sum_i ~ V(q_i)~\delta q_i$ where $\delta q_i$ is "a little charge" that we're adding and $V(q_i)$ is the voltage at the present level of charge.

For a capacitor, $V = Q / C$, let's divide the total charge Q on the capacitor into N little chunks $\delta q_1 = \delta q_2 = \dots = \delta q_N = Q / N.$ Then we'll slowly charge the capacitor by adding them on, chunk by chunk. Thus $q_n = n Q / N$.

Once we've got $n$ chunks summed, the voltage is $V(q_n) = (n Q / N) / C$, so we want to sum up:$$\begin{align}E & = & V(q_1)~ & \delta q_1 &+ & V(q_2)~ & \delta q_2 &+& \dots & + &V(q_N)~ & \delta q_N \\ & = & \left(1 \frac {Q}{NC} \right)~& \left(\frac QN\right) &+ & \left(2 \frac {Q}{NC} \right)~ & \left(\frac QN\right) &+& \dots & + &\left(N \frac {Q}{NC} \right)~ & \left(\frac QN\right) \end{align}$$and this all reduces to just: $$E = \frac{Q^2}{N^2C} \left(1 + 2 + \dots + N\right)$$Now it turns out that we can do this sum analytically because if you stack one box, and right next to it stack two boxes, and so on, that's a **triangle**.

Similarly, if you know Calculus you'll recognize the expression for $E$ as a "Riemann sum" which turns into an integral which measures an "area under the curve of $V(q).$" This curve is a straight line so the area is a triangle.

The analytical formula is $1 + 2 + \dots + N = \frac{N(N+1)}2,$ so$$E = \frac{Q^2}{2C} \frac{N^2 + N}{N^2} = \frac{Q^2}{2C} \left(1 + \frac 1N\right).$$As we break down our lump of charge into more and more little charges to get a better and better idea of what $E$ is, we find that $N$ goes to infinity and $1/N$ goes to 0, leaving us with just the factor of $1/2$.

This in turn corresponds to an area of a triangle with base $Q$ and height $V(Q) = Q/C$. The one-half comes from the area of a triangle, $(1/2) ~\text{base}\cdot\text{height}.$

Okay, so let's turn to the advanced version of this question. If you're asking, "hey, I know that this triangle formula doesn't care which is the base and which is the height, but someday I may be handling something much stranger, like $Q = C V^2$, so which function am I measuring the area under, $V(q)$ or $q(V)$?" then the answer is $V(q)$. That's where the Riemann sum from above leads us.

Comment: This makes sense. But what do you multiply consecutive terms by coefficients from 1 to N?

Comment: I am assuming numbers 1 to N are "n", which tells me how many equal little chunks you are summing up. Why do like this?

Comment: Like why add the equal-sized chunks in groups of 1,2,...N?

Comment: So that you can use the triangle formula?

Comment: @user132522 Because we have a continuous process, not a discontinuous one. Suppose a capacitor has 2 mC of charge on it, that's really N = 10^16 electrons. To figure out how much energy there is inside, put one electron in there at 0 voltage, then the next one feels a voltage due to the first one, then the third one feels a voltage due to the first two, etc. ... The voltage increases linearly as the charge enters the capacitor, which is why it does not store just an energy proportional to the charge, but quadratically increasing relative to the charge.

Comment: Are you saying that when you are on q_2, there are already two charges and because the total charge you have so far is doubled, the voltage must double proportionately?

Comment: Yes. The first electron has to fight no electrons to be on the capacitor. The second one, as it comes in, has to fight one electron. The third has to fight two. And so on. (I actually got the formula above a little wrong by that account; the $V(q_1)$ should be $0$ according to this, leading to $N (N - 1)/2$ rather than $N (N + 1)/2$, but the term disappears like $1/N$ regardless so it doesn't change anything and if you average the two it disappears completely, so...)

Comment: This is new to me. If there is only one elementary charge, there is no potential? Does this mean Q that exist on the capacitor can never be 1.6 * 10^-19 coulombs?

Comment: No, it just means that electrons don't interact with themselves; the voltage *after* the electron is on is certainly 1, but not *before*. Let me just explain this with the dopeyest analogy ever: suppose you have a party in a room, with a special rule: when you enter you must give everyone a little energy $\epsilon$. (Maybe everyone has backpacks with a reservoir of compressed air or something that you have to compress.) The *voltage* is the amount of energy a new guy must have to enter the party, and is $N \epsilon$. The total energy contained in the party room is $\epsilon~N(N-1)/2$.

Comment: So what is $V(q_1)$?    (I am very sorry that my dullness is taking your time)

Comment: Suppose we put a bunch of charge $Q$ on the capacitor in $N$ even chunks, then the amount that has been put on the capacitor by chunk number $k$ is $q_k = k Q / N$. So $q_1$ would just be $Q / N$.

Comment: when you add those small charges to the capacitor, do those charges essentially all come from the capacitors itself? If it does, then even when the first charge comes out of the plate, it is getting slowly pulled back into the plate? Does this count as voltage?

Comment: A capacitor is a **break** in a circuit and the charges which appear on each plate have to come out of a current into each side of the capacitor. But, one surprising thing is that the capacitor is connected to conductors (0 voltage drop) and thus "overall" needs to be charge-neutral, or else it would pull in or push out charges from the conductors to balance out. So the charge $+q$ on one side is always balanced by a charge $-q$ on the other, and the electric current "jumps over the gap" even though the electrons can't. So you can always pretend that $+q$ comes from the $-q$ in any circuit.

Comment: If as you said, the plate has to be neutral overall, then as soon as the first little charge (let's not call it electron, just any negative charge) comes out from one plate, the other plate sucks in another equal-sized negative charge from the conductor, so that like you said one plate is -q, the other +q! overall neutral. In the previous comment you said the first electron has no electron to fight to be on the plate, but the first electron is going towards the plate that has sucks in a negative charge and becomes negative, so it has to fight, and there is a potential difference!?

Comment: @user132522 Yes. And the fact that the first electron has to fight the second electron is why it eventually comes to equilibrium at some fixed voltage. If you connect `--(battery V)--(resistor R)--(capacitor C)--` around in a loop, the voltage drop of the battery is initially borne by R, creating a current source. This current source starts to charge the capacitor, which starts to bear more and more of the voltage drop, $V_c(t) = V~\left(1 - e^{-t/(R\,C)}\right).$ After a few $R\,C$ periods of time the capacitor is for all intents and purposes "charged" and current no longer flows through.